# Put a string into a dialog from a slected list item from a expandable list child

Tags: android, dialog, expandablelistview

I've been trying to pull details of an item selected, from my strings.xml. To a dialog pop up when i select an item from my expandable list view (child).
Sadly with little success.

This is the expandable list fragment from my NavigationDrawerFragment.
everything works great. the dialog pulls up with the template text.

```html
case 2:
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);

    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // Listview on child click listener
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            // custom dialog
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
            dialog.setTitle("Spell Details");

            // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
               TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
               String content = istDataChild.get(childPosition).toString();
               text.setText(content);
//          ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
//          image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
            return false;
        }
    });
    break;
```

My list for the expandable list view

```html
        private void prepareListData() {
            listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
            listDataChild = new HashMap<>();

            // Adding child data
            listDataHeader.add("Air");

            // Adding child data
            List<String> Air = new ArrayList<String>();
            Air.add("Air Jet\n"+"Ref. Magic 24");

            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), Air); // Header, Child data

}
```

And my adapter:

```html
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: String content = listDataChild.get(childPosition).toString();
 text.setText(content);

Comment: First of all thank you! the only error im running into now is this: 'HashMap<String, List<String>>' may not contain objects of type 'Integer' less... i'm posting a bit of my list and my adapter to help with the info

Comment: Try this,
String content = listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getistDataChild.get(childPosition).toString();

Comment: I'm still a bit green to the android studio, am i missing something with this new line. the .getistDataChild (even tried .getlistDataChild {added an L to the istData} but it cannot resolve symbol) tried to add a handler as well but it still would not recognize.

Comment: can we have a live conversation on skype / teamviewer?

Comment: sure, i cannot today, (had a tooth pulled and cannot talk well) but i can tomorrow between 10am to 4pm Mountain time.

Comment: we are conflicting times, please ping me on skype @ bhavik5491 when ever you are free

Comment: Thank you again for all of your help @ bhavik5491!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka i have figured it out!

```html
TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
String str = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(childPosition +1);
text.setText(str);
```